# Why can’t a domain name be resolved to the IP even when there is an A record in name server?

Tags: networking, dns, nameserver

I am adding my IP to `https://www.dnswl.org/selfservice/` because I need to get the reputation increased because for a very strange reason, e-mail accounts in Gmail or Hotmail save mails sent from my domain into the SPAM folder (even when e-mail deliverability from MXToolbox says that all is perfect).

Maybe I am finding the problem. When I tried to add my IP, this was the result reported by DNSWL:

```
Checking 204.93.xxx.xxx
 204.93.xxx.xxx passes validation as an IP address
 204.93.xxx.xxx could be resolved into hostname vps.example.com
 vps.example.com does not resolve back to 204.93.xxx.xxx. We will only continue with consistent DNS (IP <=> Hostname).
No valid and usable IP addresses found.
```

That is very strange because I have checked that `vps` exist in the NS as an A record, and even, when I ping to vps.example.com, the reported IP is correctly 204.93.xxx.xxx

What can be missing?

Comment: You need to establish a PTR record (aka: reverse DNS record) for you IP address that matches your domain name. That is typically done by the hosting provider. Read up more on it here: https://kb.intermedia.net/article/1317

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I have already done it.And in fact, I have used nslookup command. If I write the IP, the name is returned. If I write the name, the IP is returned. That is why I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: Try: `dig -x vps.example.com`. The returned output should contain a line like this for a PTR record: `;com.example.vps.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR`

Comment: By running that command, I received `;com.example.vps.in-addr.arpa.  IN      PTR` under `;; QUESTION SECTION:`, but the `;` before the text means that is a comment, isn't it? bellow that line, this is shown: `in-addr.arpa.           3600    IN      SOA     b.in-addr-servers.arpa. nstld.iana.org. 2020091643 1800 900 604800 3600` under `;; AUTHORITY SECTION:`. Is it wrong?

Comment: You should add that to your original question. Comments are simply hard to read and by adding this info to the main question everyone can more clearly see it and assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing that many mail servers require forward and reverse IP addresses to match, and the process of setting up reverse DNS is different from setting up forward DNS - and not something which you can do unless the upstream delegator of the IP space subdelegated the appropriate space.

Likely by far the easiest solution would be to contact your ISP/IP address provider and ask them to update the PTR record for your IP address (or at minimum to make sure reverse DNS and forward DNS match).

The alternative is to get them to delegate your IP to point to your name servers and set up an appropriate in-arpa zone (but how you do this will depend in your upstream).

I note that reverse DNS dies not use A records, they use PTR records, and they do not use the same zone (domain setup area)  as forward DNS

Comment: By contact my hosting provider is useless. My hosting is Mochahost and I have never seen a worse support than provided by them. I was already fighting with them but no solution at the moment. I have full control to my VPS and I have added the PTR record, and in fact, every tools I have used report that the IP resolves to the name, and the name resolves to the IP, however, I think that the A entry in the NS is not enough. I am pretty sure the problem in e-mail deliverability is cause of this.

Comment: Other fact I have noticed is that if I go to this page: `https://bgp.he.net/ip/204.93.169.214#_dns` (this is the real IP)........ I see that the same IP is assigned to both name servers, what is not true, both NS have different IP addresses, so maybe I am missing to check some part of NS configuration. I am not sure if this NS problem is related to the problem described in the quesstion.

Comment: Forward and reverse DNS do not match for the IP you provided which is why you have a problem.   You have 4 solutions I can see.   Get your ISP to update reverse DNS, use a VPN provider who gives you a static IP address where you can get reverse to bypass the ISP issue, change ISP providers or resurect the previous domain which appears to be available and use that...

Comment: Reverse DNS is set to mx2.showriddles.com - As at the time of this comment - that domain is not in use.  If you register the domain showriddles.com, and set up "mx2.showriddles.com with an A record for 204.93.169.214 it should work.  Of-course, this assumes no one else grabs this domain first.

Comment: PC:~$ nslookup
> 204.93.168.214
214.168.93.204.in-addr.arpa name = mx2.showriddles.com.

Comment: You made a mistake. IP has 169, and not 168. You will notice domain is other. My VPS has a static IP. I have updated my reverse DNS to point to mail.example.com, instead of vps.example.com, so I am waiting it to propagate. I made that change because https://www.dnswl.org/selfservice/ site also told that `vps` name is a generic name that is not accepted either.

Comment: When you discover the right domain name, please don't write it in the comment.